# Why the links to jobs in the 2019 developer survey?

Tags: discussion, survey-2019

I have just read the [2019 Developer Survey Results](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=announcement-banner&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2019) and a couple of links struck me as weird:

> DevOps specialists and site reliability engineers are among the highest paid, most experienced developers most satisfied with their jobs, and are looking for new jobs at the lowest levels.

> About 50% of respondents identify as full-stack developers, and about 17% consider themselves mobile developers

Both *DevOps specialists* and *full-stack developers* here links to jobs. TBH I clicked the links because I thought there'd be a definition of what each is. Why do they link to jobs? Why don't mentions of countries and other languages link to jobs related to those countries or technologies, what was special about these two? Further down, there are other links to jobs, including some from JavaScript, Python, Docker, React.js, Vue.js, MongoDB Linux and AWS, yet there were no links for the following:

> Rust, WebAssembly, and Elixir contribute to open source at the highest rates, while developers who work with VBA, C#, and SQL do so at about half those rates.

> Developers who work with languages such as VBA, F#, and Clojure have the most years of professional coding experience, while developers who work with languages like Python, PHP, and Kotlin have the fewest.

> There is two years' or more difference in the mean first age from countries like Australia and the UK compared to India and Brazil.

The links to jobs struck me as weird. There are already MANY links, including links to other parts of the results, and other resources backing up some claims, and I feel these links to jobs just made the whole thing worse to read. I can't imagine anyone reading the survery, seeing "MongoDB" and thinking "Oh yeah I needed to apply for a MongoDB job". Perhaps when there's a mention of the most-used language, or the highest-paid language there may have been a use for the link to jobs but the rest seemed useless and just made the flow worse.

Too many links worsen readability.

Comment: Jobs is one of the ways the survey and this website is funded. Not a big surprise they’d link to it. Maybe you want to use it to get a job paying those inflated figures claimed in the survey results?